# selenium webdriver opens two pages, but tests on the empty page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec

I have a selenium test that looks like

```
require 'spec_helper'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

describe '' do
   it '', :js => true do
     visit 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/'                                           
     wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds       
     wait.until { driver.find_element(:tag_name => 'svg' ) }
  end
end
```

When I ran this two firefox web pages open, one blanks and another one that visits the correct page `driver.page_source` it seems to be

`<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head></head><body></body></html>`

which would correspond to the blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visit` invokes the second page to render. Doing `driver.get` instead redirected the test page.